# Doctrine MongoDB use without ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, odm

I am using Doctrine MongoDB within Symfony2, but now I want to do some things which for me are easier without the ODM, how can I get the MongoClient or MongoCollection object?

I want to use MongoDB in the old-fashioned way like:
http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the `MongoClient` from the `DocumentManager` using

```
$mongoClient = $dm->getConnection()->getMongo();
```

Similarly, you can get a `MongoCollection` instance for document class *className* using

```
$mongoCollection = $dm->getDocumentCollection('className')->getMongoCollection();
```

or more simply

```
$mongoCollection = $dm->getConnection()->getMongo()
    ->selectCollection('collectionName');
```